# JavaFX editable TableCell for Double property

Tags: java, tableview, javafx-8, tablecell, tablecolumn

How to set up converter for TableCell to be able to edit Double property?

```
<TableColumn fx:id="priceCol" text="Price">
  <cellValueFactory>
    <PropertyValueFactory property="price" />
  </cellValueFactory>
  <cellFactory>
    <TextFieldTableCell fx:factory="forTableColumn">
      <converter>
      // ???
      </converter>
    </TextFieldTableCell>
  </cellFactory>
</TableColumn>
```

And where to find the documentation on how to set these kind of things with FXML? So far this looks really confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to do this in FXML, as far as I can see.

The [`cellFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#setCellFactory-javafx.util.Callback-) you are providing to the `TableColumn` is a factory: its type is `Callback<TableColumn<?,?>,TableCell<?,?>>`. The object returned by the call to the static factory method [`TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldTableCell.html#forTableColumn--), which is what the `FXMLLoader` creates according to the element `<TextFieldTableCell fx:factory="forTableColumn">`, is of this type.

The FXML code you provided tries to invoke `setConverter(...)` on the object returned by `TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn()`, and of course `Callback` does not define a `setConverter(...)` method, so no matter what you include as a child tag of `<converter>` it is not going to work.

As far as I am aware, there is no way in FXML to provide a parameter to a factory method invoked via `fx:factory` (which is what I think you intend), so I think you have to do this in the controller.

Of course, the latter is pretty easy. Just do

```xml
<TableColumn fx:id="priceCol" text="Price">
  <cellValueFactory>
    <PropertyValueFactory property="price" />
  </cellValueFactory>
</TableColumn>
```

in FXML, and in your controller do

```
public void initialize() {
    priceCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new DoubleStringConverter()));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I could swear I saw it somewhere, but probably just made it up... I have another tiny question: how can I make particular cell to be always in editing state?